Is it easily possible to make boost::asio::ssl export keys to a keylog
It is possible with chrome, firefox and curl to have openssl write ssl session keys to a log file by setting an environment variable SSLKEYLOGFILE. Does boost have anything similar as config?
I know it's possible to do it in code with SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback but I'm hoping I don't have to.

I guess if it's easy with openssl, then it's equally easy with boost::asio::ssl (using the respective native_handle()s). I 100% expect that you have to hook SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback yourself
